# Keep elements open on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide my main menu and logo behind the main content and have the main content push down and reveal the header when the user hovers near the top of the page.

I can get all content to push down on hover and then scroll back when the user leaves the hover area. However there are two issues that have come into play that I cannot figure out how to resolve:

1. How to get the logo clickable when it sits below the overlay
2. How to keep the header open so as to be able to click the main nav when the main nav sits below the overlay. At the moment the content scrolls back up when I try to hover over the nav items.

So what I need to be able to do is be able to click to elements below the overlay and also keep the header displaying when I scroll over the main nav area.

[Here is the code and fiddle I have so far](https://jsfiddle.net/CreativeDSG/wxu21eLb/1/):

HTML:

```
<div id="uber">
<div id="menu-toggle">
    Menu toggle (hover over me)
</div>
<header class="l-header" id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">Logo needs to be clickable</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar" id="main-navbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="l-content-main" id="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sit amet nibh id nulla placerat tincidunt sit amet vitae lectus. Vivamus porttitor sapien lorem, et condimentum dui posuere sed. Aliquam vestibulum varius posuere. Maecenas placerat nibh eu nulla lobortis scelerisque. Donec nec elit eget lorem viverra tincidunt. Nam dapibus augue arcu. Vivamus iaculis ornare velit facilisis gravida. Mauris nibh diam, ultricies in risus sit amet, fermentum blandit diam.</p>
    <p>Integer mollis varius felis, eu vehicula ante vestibulum eget. Nam consectetur eros sodales diam imperdiet, et sollicitudin ante fringilla. Pellentesque nec ligula et magna convallis sollicitudin a vel ante. Quisque tristique nec augue a fringilla. Nunc ultrices, lacus eget finibus eleifend, massa orci ultricies nisl, id fermentum nisl libero id turpis. In at ligula aliquet, interdum metus non, pretium diam. Sed in laoreet magna. Quisque at ipsum eget justo semper sodales at id augue. Maecenas massa ipsum, pharetra a aliquam eget, sollicitudin nec elit.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#menu-toggle').hover(
    function() {
        $('#main').addClass('is-active');
    },
    function() {
        $('#main').removeClass('is-active');
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
#uber {
    position: relative;
}
#menu-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: .5;
}
#header {
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
.navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
.navbar a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
}
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 80px 50px;
    background: lightgrey;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 300ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 300ms ease;
    transition:         all 300ms ease;
    z-index: 10;
}
#main p {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#main.is-active {
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `#header` selector to your `jQuery` causing the `is-active` class to be applied when you hover over either `#menu-toggle` or the `#header`.

```
$('#menu-toggle, #header').hover(
    function() {
        $('#main').addClass('is-active');
    },
    function() {
        $('#main').removeClass('is-active');
    }
);
```

The logo link is not clickable because the `#menu-toggle` is overlaying it. Reduce the height of the `div` to make the underlying elements available - `25px` seems to work.

```
#menu-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/wxu21eLb/6/

Comment: This works great for the second issue, thank you. Is there a way though to make the elements under the overlay clickable, i.e. the logo link?

Comment: @Darren sorry, didn't see that. updated the answer, you need to reduce the height of `#menu-toggle`.

Comment: Thanks for this. The only issue I was facing with the second part was I was asked to keep the hover area as big as the whole main header region, hence why I was having trouble finding a way to make the logo clickable. The append answer from guest271314 provided a way around this but I will keep them both in mind for future sites. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.appendTo()`

```
$('#menu-toggle').hover(
    function() {
        $(".logo a").appendTo(this);
        $('#main').addClass('is-active');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find("a").appendTo(".logo");
        $('#main').removeClass('is-active');

    }
);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wxu21eLb/4/

Comment: The append worked great along with the answer from doublesharp this helped solve both my problems. Thanks for your help on this.